# HTD3 tooth pulley design

Tags: pulleys

I try to design a HTD3 pulley, but I don't know, how the teeth exactly should look like. I found the following specification:

[image]

But this seems to be wrong, since I found some HTD3 STL files and overlapped them and the teeth form seems different. What is the correct design for a HTD pulley?

Comment: Why do you trust the STLs?

Comment: I don't trust them, but I found different specifications for the HTD pulleys, so I'm a bit concerned, something is wrong

Comment: Which specifications did you find in addition to the posted image?

Comment: Ok, I have seen, that all specifications lead to the design above, so this seems correct, thank you